# Django Rest-Framework price range additional filter?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following Django view in my Django Rest-Framework API

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend, RangeFilter, FilterSet
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter, SearchFilter

from rest_framework import generics
from api.serializers import UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import permissions
from api.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly

from MyGameDBWebsite.models import Game, GameDeveloper, GameGenre, GameConsole
from api.serializers import GameSerializer, DeveloperSerializer, GenreSerializer, ConsoleSerializer


class GameList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    serializer_class = GameSerializer

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter, SearchFilter,)
    filter_fields = ('owner__username', 'id', 'game_title', 'game_developer_name', 'game_console',
                     'game_genre', 'game_release_year', 'game_price',)

    ordering_fields = ('owner__username', 'id', 'game_title', 'game_developer_name', 'game_console',
                       'game_genre', 'game_release_year', 'game_price',)

    search_fields = ('game_title', 'game_release_year', 'game_price',)

    queryset = Game.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

My output URL is the following: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?owner__username=&id=&game_title=&game_developer_name=&game_console=&game_genre=&game_release_year=&game_price=

I want create a price range so that i can call the API from URL to get the results in a price range

Answer (score 3):

You should define a [**`filterset_class`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class) and use it in your views.

In the case of **`RangeFilter`**, You should define your price field with [**`RangeFilter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#rangefilter)

#### Example

```
class GameFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    game_price = filters.RangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['game_price']
```

and hence your url will be as, `/api/?game_price_min=123&game_price_max=321`

Comment: can't i have the range plus the above url combination?

Comment: the range is something with two values, right? and you have only one parameter regarding it on your urls, which is `game_price`. Anyway, how do you plan to pass the range value(the two values) with a single url param?

Comment: apart from that, DRF or django-filter won't detect the range filter from the given url unless you given it in a proper syntax/settings

Comment: Like this : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?owner__username=&id=&game_title=&game_developer_name=&game_console=&game_genre=&game_release_year=&game_price= example given from Develpoper1 all games with a price range

Comment: I dont understand that

Comment: sorry i have on the above code some search filter fields. Like 'game_title', 'game_developer_name', etc. i use the filter DjangoFilterBackend and the appropriate fields 'game_title', 'game_developer_name',, when i run a back-end search i get the following URL i send above. i would like to add a price filter to this url so i can make complex search like all the games from a developer within a price range. hope i helped

Comment: as per your current settings, without a `filterset_class`, it's not possible to use the `RangeFilter`

Comment: Thank you very much i fount out how to do it i just need to include the rest of the field in my filterset_class

Comment: Is it possible to extract the the URL of the game by ID?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a FilterSet
For more advanced filtering requirements you can specify a FilterSet class that should be used by the view. For example:

```
import django_filters
from myapp.models import Game
from myapp.serializers import GameSerializer
from rest_framework import generics


class GameListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
min_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="price", lookup_type='gte')
max_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="price", lookup_type='lte')
class Meta:
    model = Game
    fields = ['min_price', 'max_price']


class GameList(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = Game.objects.all()
serializer_class = GameSerializer
filter_class = GameListFilter
```

Which will allow you to make requests such as:

```
http://example.com/api/games?max_price=8.00
```